# Laravel public/js/app.js huge (1.5MB) for simple app

Tags: laravel-6

I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/IyM4uH2fhMU to get basic Laravel setup with auth functionality with a bootstrap preset. After inspecting my files i saw the public/js.app.js being about 1.5MB. My question is, is this normal? I think it is not ok for websites to have a big file to download first.

Answer (score 0):

have you try run `npm run production`? It looks like you are running in development mode

Comment: Thanks for your help! That worked and reduced the public/app.js to 330kb or some. However i had an error running npm run production. Found here the exact problem and upgrading the sass loader solved it, see https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/npm-run-prod-fails-with-bootstrap?page=1